# How would you translate Marcus Aurelius's self-description from Greek into Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, greek, translation-check, sentence-translation

Marcus Aurelius describes himself succinctly and humbly in the third book of his *Meditations*. I would like to come up with a Latin translation, but have a few questions on diction.

> ἔτι δὲ ὁ ἐν σοὶ θεὸς ἔστω προστάτης ζῴου ἄρρενος καὶ πρεσβύτου καὶ πολιτικοῦ καὶ Ῥωμαίου καὶ ἄρχοντος, ...
>
> And yet let the god within thee be a guardian of a living being, male, mature in years, a statesman, a Roman, and a ruler, ...

([*Meditations* 3.5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Aur.%203.5&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0641))

Here's my best shot at a Latin translation, but I'm sure there are many mistakes.

> Tamen autem deus in tibi sit vindex<sup>2</sup> animi<sup>3</sup> masculi et maturi et civis<sup>4</sup> et Romani et imperatoris.<sup>5</sup>

What changes would you suggest? What errors did I make?

---

<sup>1</sup> Does "deus in tibi sit" look right to you?
<sup>2</sup> I was on the fence between vindex and defensor, but perhaps both are wrong.
<sup>3</sup> On the fence between animi and vitae, but the latter would necessitate feminine adjectives.
<sup>4</sup> The Greek πολιτικός could be "statesman" or "citizen". How would you say "statesman"?
<sup>5</sup> The adjectives are genitive by analogy to the Greek. But I'm not sure about this choice.

^ The five degradations of <strike>Hesiod</strike> my Latin sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My thoughts to get things started:

1. *Deus in tibi* definitely isn't right, because the Latin preposition *in* never has a dative with it. You want *in te* (ablative).
2. I have a strong suspicion that the προστάτης bit is meant to render the Latin word *genius*. After all, 'guardian of a living being, male,' is practically the dictionary definition of *genius*. And this word also had special meaning when applied to the emperor and his divinity. In that case, you can probably just say *genius viri* instead of *vindex animi masculini*.
3. See #2.
4. One way of rendering 'statesman' would be *vir civilis*, so you could likely get away with using just the adjective *civilis* here, together with your other adjectives. (Or, I suppose you could work in some sort of periphrasis, such as *peritus rei publicae gubernandae*, depending on what you think it means to be statesman.)
5. Grammatically, yes, the words need to be genitive for the way you've phrased this.

Other points:

- I'm not at all sure *tamen* is correct for ἔτι δέ, but I can't find my copy of Denniston's *Greek particles* at the moment. Both *tamen* and ἔτι do translate as 'still' in English, but the English word is ambiguous: *tamen* is 'still' in the sense of 'nevertheless'; whereas ἔτι is (usually, at least) more temporal (as in 'I'm still here') or even about degree (as in 'still greater rewards'). At any rate, using both *tamen* and *autem* as you've done is definite overkill.
- I guess *maturus* works for πρεσβύτης; *senex* seems the more obvious choice though, especially because Marcus Aurelius seems to be going for very basic terminology that's rooted in Roman tradition, even though he's expressing it in Greek: man, citizen/statesman, elder, Roman – and even emperor (as an extension of the traditional term *imperator*).

Comment: Thank you for your points. Genius, civilis, and senex are all good suggestions. Especially genius. And I agree, I did suspect that tamen autem was overkill. I guess that spending so much time with the Vulgate, I wanted to translate a particle with a particle. I still do, if possible. I should look into how St. Jerome translates *eti de*.

Comment: **Follow-up:** I'm accepting this answer for now because it is very good. But if a new answer shows up that adds new information I'll reconsider my choice.